# WPF InkCanvas: Being in ink mode can i fire children_mousedown, children_mouseup events?

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, inkcanvas

In an `InkCanvas`, I have some `UIElement`s as children.

`UIElement`s have events like `uielement_mousedown`, `uielement_mouseup` etc.

If I am in inkcanvas ink mode, can I fire the `uielement_mousedown`, `uielement_mouseup` events?

Answer (score 0):

You can always fire the events and handle them from inkCanvas. Its just that they will not act to the user response in ink mode, so if child `UIElement`s within the `InkCanvas` are fixed hosted (i.e. not added at run time), you can handle the moseEnter and mouseLeave events for the `UIElement` and in the `MouseEnter` you will change the the `InkCanvas` `EditingMode` to **Select** and at `MouseLeave` change the `EditingMode` to **Ink**. This way they become responsive to the user input (key, mouse etc.) while mouse is in them.

Does this answer your query?

Comment: Inkcanvas childrens are not fixed in design. Am adding them dynamically / runtime. Now , Is there any way to handle Mouseenter / leave events in ink mode ?